# Visual Sourcesafe, sharing: commits to wrong location

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I have a project under my management.

It has the following structure:

$/Code/MainSolution
$/Code/Branches

I want to branch the MainSolution in $/Code/Branches

So I do it, (it works perfectly), I set a working folder for that project and do a 'get latest'.

But when I open that solution in Visual Studio 2005 it identifies every file as new (+ sign in front of the file) and when I commit it it goes to

$/Data/NameOfTheBranch

Why does it do that? Why doesn't it follow MY rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to File, Source Control, Change
   Source Control (at least on VS2008).
2. Look at the Server Binding column.
   Generally you want the binding to
   point to the solution's root project
   directory in VSS for the solution
   **and** all the projects.  If not, then:
3. Unbind **all** the projects and the
   solution.
4. Shift-select the entire list.
5. Bind everything to the solution root.

If you do this before branching and pinning the project, it will be easier.  Doing it afterward you will have to branch the .sln file and perhaps the .vcproj and the .vspscc as well for the modifications to be saved correctly.

[Here's](http://alinconstantin.members.winisp.net/webdocs/scc/SccFiles.htm) a good reference for the files VSS and Visual Studio manage.  These files can easily get out-of-whack.

I administered a VSS database for too many years and recently switched to Mercurial and haven't looked back.  Branching and merging in VSS is horrible.

Answer (score 2):

I usually make all vcproj files under solution have the following:

```
SccProjectName = "SAK"
SccLocalPath = "SAK"
SccAuxPath = "SAK"
SccProvider = "SAK"
```

This will make it pick up the sourcesafe information from the solution file.  Make sure solution file is branched, not shared in the 2 branches.  Open the branched solution and then go to "Change Source Control" and bind the solution to the correct location in SourceSafe.
This is all rather fragile (or perhaps I don't fully understand it) but I usually just poke at it until it works.
And, as usual: if at all possible migrate to a different source control system.  Perforce, Subversion, Mercurial...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by your code example.

Comment: You open the vcproj file with a text editor and replace whatever values this variable have with "SAK".  This will dissociate the project from the SourceSafe and you will use the sln file to associate the proj with the sourcesafe.  This is nice because you can now change the project location in SS in only one place (we have 60 projects in one of our solutions!).  Then when you branch you just need to branch the solution and change SS binding in it, instead of changing it both in solution and projects.

Comment: But will the branch still work? Will it still be associated with the trunk? And can I merge after wards? (is that even possible?...)

Comment: My branches are shared copies of the trunk pinned to a version at which I did the copy.  When i need to make a change to a file in an older branch, that when I actually branch it (because obviously can't modify pinned file).  I don't use SS merge functionality and do merges manually, but I'm not sure *why* I'm doing it manually.